# GetResponseAsync png link url - Parameter not valid

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, httpwebrequest

I have to write a Windows Form application that print a png from url, I'd like to write the code asynchronously.
Here is my **working code** (sync)

```
public Bitmap GetImage()
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.basilicasanmarco.it/wp-content/themes/tema-basilicasmarco/library/images/patriarcato.png");
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
    }
    return bmp;
}

private void PrintImage(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var imag = GetImage())
    {
        if (imag == null)
            return;
        var newHeight = mainImage.Height;
        var rapporto = newHeight / (double) imag.Height;
        var newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(rapporto * imag.Width);
        var imageLocationX = Convert.ToInt32((mainImage.Width - newWidth) / 2.0);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imag, imageLocationX, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to write the same code in a async await way, here is my snippet:

```
public async Task<Bitmap> GetImage()
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.basilicasanmarco.it/wp-content/themes/tema-basilicasmarco/library/images/patriarcato.png");
    using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
    }
    return bmp;
}

private async Task PrintImageAsync(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var imag = await GetImage())
    {
        var newHeight = mainImage.Height;
        var rapporto = newHeight / (double) imag.Height;
        var newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(rapporto * imag.Width);
        var imageLocationX = Convert.ToInt32((mainImage.Width - newWidth) / 2.0);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imag, imageLocationX, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
}
```

The first synchronous code works well, when I turn to the async part I have the "Parameter not valid" exception (System.Drawing exception) in the

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(imag, imageLocationX, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
```

code.
The Bitmap obtained seems ok, it has the correct Width and Height but something is wrong inside it, only in the asynchronous method.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:
I await the method in the `Paint` method of a `Panel` in the following way:

```
this.panel.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.mainImage_Paint);

private async void mainImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    await PrintImageAsync(e);
}
```

What I want to obtain is to paint the downloaded image in a Panel instead that a PictureBox because I need a more low-level approach.

Comment: How do you invoke PrintImageAsync? Where do you get the PaintEventArgs? Are you calling this inside the Paint event? That part is missing yet it is crucial to see what's wrong

Comment: How do you call this matters becuase the graphics pointer is probably not pointing to the current graphics of the picture box or whatever you are trying to draw into when the image is downloaded.

Comment: @OguzOzgul very interesting, I didn't think about it. I added to the question, as you guess, I call inside a Paint event. I'd like to print the downloaded Image inside a Panel.

Comment: Exactly as I say, the Graphics object is not valid anymore. While you wait with await, the caller of Paint does not. Doing this in Paint this way can also cause other problems. Do you want the image to be downloaded every time the Paint event is invoked? I don't think so. I am posting an answer now, please let me know if it helps.

Comment: You hit the point: I looked only at the Bitmap as the source of my error but I was wrong: the Bitmap anche the async implementation is ok, the problem was the Graphics object in Paint method. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. The image is beautiful by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Paint event handler is invoked for each re-draw of the control and you probably don't want to download the image every time this happens.

When the event handler is invoked, it seems like accessing the graphics object in the event args (e) parameter succeeds BEFORE an async operation but FAILS after an await.

Therefore;

It is not clear what triggers the download of the image in you source code, but if trying to do it async, get the image asynchronously and keep it in a field, and paint it on your panel if it is available.

The following assumes that you download the image directly, without any user action, and the place for this is the async void Form_Load(): (You can see that the image is downloaded in the background!)

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.panel1.Paint += this.mainImage_Paint;
    downloadedBitmap = await GetImage();
    // When we got the image, invalidate the panel to trigger a re-paint
    this.panel1.Invalidate();
}

// Keep the downloaded image in a field:
private Image downloadedBitmap;

private async void mainImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (downloadedBitmap != null)
    {
        var newHeight = mainImage.Height;
        var rapporto = newHeight / (double)downloadedBitmap.Height;
        var newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(rapporto * downloadedBitmap.Width);
        var imageLocationX = Convert.ToInt32((mainImage.Width - newWidth) / 2.0);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(downloadedBitmap, imageLocationX, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
}
```